# Does Karate support WebSocket continuation frames?

Tags: karate

We just found out that our WebApi returns trough the WebSocket protocol the message in chunks. These are continuation frames as per [RFC6455 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). While we listen only the first frame is retrieved from Karate and the others lost. This is always a string with 4082 chars length and around 16k bytes size. Is there a way to make Karate listen until the final frame is received so the whole message can be evaluated?

Here is a visualization from Fiddler showing how the frames are received:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dev of Karate here. We are interested in closing gaps if any, so would you be able to help us get a sample WebSocket endpoint, maybe public or some sample code for us to replicate.

Karate uses Netty as the underlying library. A [quick search](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/ContinuationWebSocketFrame.html) tells me that it would be easy to support continuation frames if we don't already. Feel free to open a feature request to discuss further.

Comment: our API is on .Net Core and we can build you a local executable for Linux/Windows - what operating system do you use?  We would need the linux version as well.

Comment: @PlamenGospodinov great ! I am on a Mac, but am comfortable with Linux + Docker. also can work with Windows (via VM) but least preferred. once implemented, karate is cross-platform and will work on linux - if that was what you asked in the last sentence.

Comment: nice, we will prepare a Linux Docker image and open a feature request in GitHub.